# amp-access type server: when will this be available?

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

[documentation says](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/dynamic/amp-access)
*The "server" option is under design discussion and these docs will be updated when it is ready.*

Question: is there a timing known for this? Can it already be used?

We want to use AMP for paywalled content.
type="client" is not an option (not safe enough) => type="server" solves this

I understand we could already implement it on our side:
 - when ip is from google range: serving full document
 - when ip is not: excluding/including the appropriate parts
but if I understand it correctly we should not go into production with this yet? We should wait until it is ready and Google AMP Cache supports it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's an experimental approach implemented, publisher that want to use it should contact [google group amphtml-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/amphtml-discuss/ZN6oBzeONdM) (whitelisting of publisher is needed)

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be used, as the `Availability` status is `Stable` (try it in your development site). But take note that the extension is under active development so changes may still happen. I'm not sure about the timing but you can always check the [AMP Access Specification github page](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-access/amp-access.md) or [amp-access page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/dynamic/amp-access) to be updated on the changes. Hope this help.

Comment: -"try it in your development site"
I don't see how? Main question: will Google AMP Cache handle this right? (server side remove the protected sections when no access)
The only option to "test" this is I see: put something in production with the proper amp links => so Google can find it, hopefully puts it in AMP cache and I (+ and everyone else..) can "test" how Google Cache handles it

Comment: some more research:
*2016/01/18* initial amp-access doc (server: under design discussion - will be updated when it is ready)  
*2016/01/29* github issue: ["will not arrive for some time"](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/1632)  
*2016/04/22* doc: Stable (still with "when it is ready")  
*2017/03/16* main feature (server side removing elements) [got removed from AMP cache modifications best practices](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/commit/f9e7d)
"is currently implemented but not being used" implemented in what? Google AMP Cache or some other cache? but nobody uses it?